# Why does this string return this way

Tags: jython

Why does this code return jython string and not pjthon string?

```
str = "python string"
new_str = "j" + str[1:]
print(new_str)
```

result is jython string

Answer (score 0):

This code is just Python, not Jython specific.
It is using String slicing, which syntax looks like: `str[ start_pos:end_pos:step ]`

`str[1:]` is a slice of `"python string"`, starting at index `1` with no end position or step size, will result in `"ython string"`. (in Python, the first element is at index 0)

`new_str = "j" + str[1:]` will result in `new_str = "j" + "ython string"`, which will set `new_str` to `"jython string"`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9LNAtP//xeXFCnYKigVgLkKQF5mXroSV15qeTxUJktJQRskHm1oFctVAJQu0YDKav7/DwA)